# Make link for last page visited in current website?

Tags: drupal, hyperlink

How can I make a link which goes to the last page visited which was part of the current site?

Another way of saying this is, I need a link which is like the browser back button, unless the last page visited was a different website. If this is the case the link could either go to the last page on the current site that was visited, or an arbitrary back up could be used.

UPDATE. Would javascript be the easiest solution? The code below works as a back button:
 [Go Back]

So, could I add some logic that made it work as normal if the last page was part of the current site, and provided a back up if the last page visited wasn't from my site? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work, but you'll need more logic to handle the first visit, and I'm not sure if `request_uri` returns the exact format you need for the link:

```
<a href="<?php print $_SESSION('last_page'); ?>">Back</a>
<?php $_SESSION('last_page') = request_uri(); ?>
```

Comment: @jdln, see [this page](http://drupal.org/node/337959) for how to use php snippets in drupal.

Comment: Ive read the page but im still not sure how to use the code. Ive used php snippets before eg conditional php, printing the path to the site's base, etc. However I only understand the very basics of whats going on. Thanks

Comment: Ive marked your answer as correct as the reason I havn't used it is my lack of PHP knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

NeXXeuS came up with a jQuery solution here:

[Javascript / jQuery back button - so long as last page was part of current site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490466/javascript-jquery-back-button-so-long-as-last-page-was-part-of-current-site/5490490#5490490)
Thanks