# Javascript / jQuery back button - so long as last page was part of current site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, back

With the code below I can make a 'back' button, but is there a way of making the link require that the last page was part of the current site?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.back').click(function(){
        parent.history.back();
        return false;
    });
});
```

If the last page wasn't part of the current site then ideally id like to be able to specify a backup link.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a good reason for trying to mimic behavior already performed by the browser?

Comment: The short answer is 'because my client has asked me'. Its for a 'continue shopping' link so it should go back to the previous category. The issue is that there are 2 different potential categories for each product.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using `document.referrer`?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.back').click(function(){
        if(document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.hostname) != -1){
            parent.history.back();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Works, but can I make the jquery not alter the link when the last page was not part of the site? At the moment the code stops the link that was already there from working.

Comment: It's important to note that will fail when the referrer is not passed to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do this.

But you could use a cookie

psuedo code

```
if !cookie_exists()
    disable_back_button()
    create_cookie()
```

Then delete the cookie when the user leaves.

Referrer can be edited, so I don't recommend that

but I also don't recommend doing this at all, its annoying.